# Ruby on Rails - rails generate rspec:installが実行できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

こんにちわ。rails初心者です。
現在Railsチュートリアル第3章を進めています。そこで下記コマンドを実行するとエラーが出てしまいました。解決する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスください。お願いします。

実行コマンド

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

エラー

```
/Users/mofuty/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)
    from /Users/mofuty/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mofuty/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
    from /Users/mofuty/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

Comment: `config/application.rb` の内容を、ここに貼ってみてはいかがでしょう。エラーメッセージ中の [`active_job` は Rails 4.2 からの機能](http://qiita.com/ryohashimoto/items/2f8fd685920a5318def4) らしいのですが、実際に使っている Rails のバージョンは 4.0 であるように見受けられます。なぜそのようになっているかまではわかりませんので、まずは足りない情報を補うことが先決だと考えました。できれば、プロジェクト全体を github などを使って公開できると、より詳しい人からのアドバイスがもらえるかと考えます。

Comment: @KoRoN さん、アドバイスありがとうございます。ひとまず、`config/application.rb` の内容を追記しました。github公開も進めます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>試しに `bundle exec rails generate rspec:install` を実行してみてください。</s>

たしかにapplication.rbがちょっと変ですね。
4.0系だとこんな感じになるはずです。

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module CbMorning
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

`active_job`とかは4.0系では通常出てこないので、一度このコードに置き換えてみてください。

原因はよくわかりませんが、もしかすると4.2系の実行環境で rails newしてしまったのかもしれません。

### 追記

4.2系でrails newしていると、今後他にも問題が出てくるかもしれません。
4.0.5で作っていくなら、バージョンを指定してrails newし直した方が早いかもです。

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.0
# 4.0.5ではない場合
rails _4.0.5_ new sample_app
```

Comment: @junichi-itoさん
実行しましたが、同様のエラーが出ました。

Comment: @junichi-itoさん まさにおっしゃる通りでした。4.2系でrails new したがためにこうなったようです。再構築すると無事 `rails generate rspec:install` できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したのであれば良かったです。あと、意外と困っている人が多いようなので、こんな記事を書きました。こちらも参考にしてみてください。
[Railsチュートリアルでrails newするときはバージョンを指定しよう](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/f3bde6e46afbeba8cb82)

Comment: 記事読みました。
初心者の場合railsチュートリアルを読んでいるだけだと原因が突き止めにくいエラーが往々にしてあるので、
こういう情報提供やコミュニティは励みになります。ありがとうございました！